# jQuery UI autocomplete $.widget not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to extend ui.autocomplete by using widget factory:

```
$.widget( "custom.myautocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
      .text(item.label)
      .appendTo( ul ); 
  }
});

$(function() {
  $("#inp").myautocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"]
  })
});
```

Searching works fine, but item selection does not work.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5uu393y/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a later version of jquery. It works for me with 1.10 and 1.11

```
code unchanged
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5uu393y/7/